# What's the origin of the "accidental boob grab" trope?

Tags: tropes, anime-history, manga-history

I was just wondering where the trope of the protagonist tripping and accidentally groping someone first came from.

What's the origin of this trope?

Comment: I think the earlier occurences of this were in Takahashi Rumiko's mangas, like Ranma 1/2 or Urusai Yatsura

Comment: It's difficult to trace the first who did it, but it got popularized by Love Hina (2000).

Answer (score -1):

I will try to answer.
I still don't know what is the pioneer of that fan service. But all I know that a shot like "Oops I grabbed your boobs accidentally" is very common in *manga*, especially *shounen manga*. Manga creator created this 'fan service' because shounen manga usually read by teenage young boy. Also, they believe, in teenage, young boy will love this kinda jokes because of for example they are going through puberty.

**Here are my references**

Book : "Understanding Manga and Anime" by Robin E. Brenner

Quora : [Why do anime characters show underwear](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-anime-characters-show-underwear)

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! We know that the trope is popular, but the question is about how and when it began, so if you don't know that, then please don't post an answer.

Comment: Hi, while we appreciate the additional info, unfortunately this answer is missing the core question of how and when it happened. Consider [edit]ing if it can be improved, thanks!